# React-Redux mapStateToProps with dynamic (uid based) path

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

I am new to React and React-Redux.  I'm trying to pass "mapStateToProps" using a dynamic pathway depending on the users id. The basic code being used follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    console.log(state);
    console.log(state.firebase.auth.uid); <===== THIS DISPLAYS THE USERS ID, PROVING THE PATH EXISTS

    return {

        courses: `state.firestore.ordered.${state.firebase.auth.uid}`, <======= THIS LINE IS AN ERROR EVEN THOUGH THE PATH EXISTS

    }
}
```

The code works fine if I manually type in the users ID.  Lets say the users ID is "12345", then replacing that line with

```
courses: state.firestore.ordered.12345, <======= THIS LINE WOULD WORK
```

Any clarification as to why this doesn't work and an alternative method of making this work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: courses: state.firestore.ordered(` nameofuserstable/${state.firebase.auth.uid} `); can you try this and check, for me looks like there is a syntax error that is preventing the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access dynamic property in JS object, you need to use square braces

```
    courses: state.firestore.ordered[state.firebase.auth.uid]
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! :) I knew it was something simple and was trying all sorts of syntax but not this one!